# Security Group Variables

Tags: powershell

Little bit of background: the company I work for have a lot of groups in AD 600 thousand+. I have removed much of these and have it now down to arround 7000. The majority of these groups are security groups that are applied to folders / NTFS etc. for permission control.

I have a script (PowerShell) that we are using to create the new folders and also add the permissons based on some drop down boxes and input boxes in a form.

the problem I am having is passing the group name to a variable as I want each group added to the folder I create.

Example:

```
Group name : GG COLORADO FOREST STANDARD L
```

This broken down is Global Group - Location - Business group - Department - Permissions.

The variable I have for this is:

```
$GroupName = "mydomain\GG " + $bussinessgroup + $department  +  $aclarray[$i]
```

From the form drop down list I select the business group bit COLORADO FOREST, then I have a global variable for department - `$department = "STANDARD", "FINANCE","WORKS"`. The variables should then be added up - I could do it with my old groups no problems at all but I didnt have as many spaces in the group name - is there a way to add spaces in?

Comment: Six hundred *thousand* groups? That's insane.

Answer (score 0):

To add spaces you could simply add spaces:

```
$GroupName = "mydomain\GG " + $bussinessgroup + ' ' + $department + ' ' + aclarray[$i]
```

A more PoSh approach, however, would be to use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
$GroupName = "mydomain\GG {0} {1} {2}" -f $bussinessgroup, $department, aclarray[$i]
```